# How to update the content of a TextView in a fragment in navagation drawer in Android

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I'am new to Android application developpement. I'am trying to create an application using navigation drawer. I created an apllication with the navigation drawer template with android studio. Then i changed it to redirect the user to a new fragment_layout each time he chooses a new item in the navigation menu. Now, my first fragment contains a listview, and onclick on one item of the list i am redirected to a detailfragment which contains a TextView.
When i tried to populate this TextView with details of the selected item i had a null pointer exception.After two days of research and trying to find out what is the problem i discovered that my visible fragment returns false when i call fragment.isInLayout().
Thanks for your help.
 My code :
Creation of a new fragment :

```
VideoDetailFragment fragment = new VideoDetailFragment(); 
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("title", title)
    fragment.setArguments(bundle); 
 FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();   
 transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
       transaction.addToBackStack(null);

        // Commit the transaction
        transaction.commit();

        getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
        if (fragment.isInLayout()) {
            fragment.replaceText("Lalala");}
```

And the method replaceText code is :

```
 public  void replaceText(String text){


textView.setText(text);
 }
```

The problem is that the methode replaceText is not reached And when i remove the if statement a null pointer exception is raised saying that i can not write in the textView

EDIT: I think the problem is with `transaction.replace(R.id.container,fragment);`, maybe there is another alternative to replace a fragment_layout content. Because, i have the `VideoDetailFragment` displayed in the simulator and i can't change it's content, Also when i tired `VideoDetailFragment fragment1 = (VideoDetailFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container);`
 it gave me a cast exception.
Thanks a lot for your help, really need it :)

Comment: Could you post the code that isn't working? Otherwise it'll be difficult to figure out what's going wrong...

Comment: Try to put the `getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
        if (fragment.isInLayout()) {
            fragment.replaceText("Lalala");}  ` before the `transaction.commit();` statement

Comment: I have the same result , it can not reach the `fragment.replaceText("Lalala");`

Answer (score 0):

Try to do something like this:

```
Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString(key, value);
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

Then in your second Fragment, retrieve the data (you could do it for example in `onCreate()`) with:

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
int myString = bundle.getString(key, ""); //the second parameter is a default value
```

Or show your code to see where do you get NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

```
YourFragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.your_fragment);

if (fragment != null) {
   fragment.yourUpdateDataMethod(youData);
}
```

Comment: I think i can't use findFragmentById, because in my main activity i have two fragments one for the menu and the other called 'container' for the page content. The container fragment is populated with the HomeFragment and i want to replace it with VideoDetailFragment.

Comment: I tried your code , unfortunatelly it raises an exception : **HomeFragment cannot be cast to VideoDetailFragment** . I think the problem is the `transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);` methode does replace the layout in the simulator but it stiil work like it wasn't replaced, Do you have any idea why? Thanks :)